# Automate sending response to subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.7

I have a program that, when run from Windows Command Prompt requires me to press enter to a number of questions. I am trying to automate the process of running the program and pressing enter from Python.

**My attempt**

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

p = subprocess.Popen(['bcontroller','login','aws'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for _ in range(5):
    sleep(10)
    p.communicate(input=b'\n')
```

When I run this, I first get a warning:

> error: Incorrect function.

Then after ~ 10 seconds, *subprocess* throws an error that stops execution:

> ValueError: write to closed file

Does anyone know what might be wrong?